# IF ... (AND) statement run time error "13"

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, runtime-error

I need help with my if statements. In the code show below: The first if ... then section works just as intended, however the second section creates a run time error "13". Can someone please explain me how to fix this issue? / what i'm doing wrong?

```
Sub ASN_BaaN3()
Dim i As Integer
i = 0

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("BaaN").Activate

Do While ThisWorkbook.Sheets("BaaN").Cells(2 + i, 1) <> ""

    'CHECK NON SERIALIZED
    If Range("J" & 2 + i).Value = "N" Then
        Range("P" & 2 + i).Value = "Ok, Non Serialized"
        Range("P" & 2 + i).EntireRow.Interior.Color = RGB(198, 239, 206)
    End If

    If Range("J" & 2 + i).Value = "Y" And _
    Range("M" & 2 + i).Value = "ACK" And _
    Range("o" & 2 + i).Value = "TRUE" Then
        Range("P" & 2 + i).Value = "Ok, Non Serialized"
        Range("P" & 2 + i).EntireRow.Interior.Color = RGB(198, 239, 206)
    End If

    i = i + 1
Loop

End Sub
```

when typing the code like this i get the same error:

```
    If Range("J" & 2 + i).Value = "Y" Then
    If Range("M" & 2 + i).Value = "ACK" Then
    If Range("O" & 2 + i).Value = "TRUE" Then
        Range("P" & 2 + i).Value = "Ok, Non Serialized"
        Range("P" & 2 + i).EntireRow.Interior.Color = RGB(198, 239, 206)
    End If
    End If
    End If
```

Also when typing the code like this

```
    If Range("J" & 2 + i).Value = "Y" Then
    If Range("M" & 2 + i).Value = "Y" Then
```

Please help!

Comment: As a side point, is there any reason you didn't use `i=2` at the beginning and remove *allll* that `2 + i` stuff?

Comment: You must have some `#NA` (or other error) in the cell `("M" & 2 + i)`.

Comment: First off, make sure you qualify all of your range references. Currently, you are using the implicit Activesheet reference which may be what you intend at the time of the code running, or it may not. If the activesheet changes you wont know it is operating on the wrong sheet until it is potentially too late.

As A.S.H has suggested, you likely have some kind of error within the cell that is causing the code to throw an error of its own. VBA cannot implicitly compare an error type to a string type. Try debug.Printing the values you are trying to compare so you can see what the code sees.